# Why does my side-scroller character move in the wrong direction?

Tags: camera, movement, lwjgl

I'm trying to understand why my rectangle moves in the opposite direction I want it to.

I have a `float` for translation:

```
 glTranslatef(translate_x, 0, 0);

 if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
        translate_x += 5;
 }
```

This is the rectangle I'm drawing (I did use `glpush` and -`pop`):

```
glColor3f(250, 0, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(400, 400); // Upper-left
    glVertex2i(450, 400); // Upper-right
    glVertex2i(450, 450); // Bottom-right
    glVertex2i(400, 450); // Bottom-left
glEnd();
```

Whenever I press the spacebar, the rectangle moves to the opposite direction of where I want it to move. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glTranslatef moves the camera, and not what it is looking at. So adding 5 to the x-axis will make the camera move to the right, hence making it look like the rectangle is moving to the left. Subtracting 5 will make the rectangle go to the right.

Comment: Is this the normal way to do it? Should I just use a camera?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your rectangle to move on the same axis but in the opposite direction, you have to change the sign of the translation value.

```
glTranslatef(-translate_x, 0, 0);
```

Comment: A little short but to the point, you could elaborate on the Askers code and include their if statement in the answer.

Comment: Ok I take notes, thank you. I wanted the changes to be easily spotted.